# Obfuscate two JARs separately with Maven / Proguard

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, proguard

I use maven to manage a core package and two appliaction packages that both depends on the core package. For technical reasons, I can't make a full assembly for each application package, which means that I've to distribute each application package with the core package as a separate JAR which will be put in the classpath of the application.

I also need to obfuctate my JARs. I can achieve this easily for a single assembly, however, I'm not sure if it is possible to obfuscate all classes while keeping my JAR separated ?

Someone has already been faced to this problem, and if so, is there any possibility to do this with maven and proguard ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although I not sure if you could obfuscate two jars separately which depend on each other, but I have seen similar things done.

This can be achievedi by keeping some clean interface(s) between the two jars. This will allow you to keep the interface between the jars as unobfuscated and rest of the classes can be safely obfuscated without breaking the dependency.

This was done on one of the product I have worked on which exposed public APIs to clients to code to but the implementation classes were obfuscated.

This solution could be painful to implement practically and will depend on degree of inter dependency between your two jars.